# Why do I get a 404 error when I try to access my rails site using https?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, http-status-code-404, passenger

My server is currently hosting a php site. This site uses ssl for certain pages already. Now I am transitioning over to rails, and all my new rails apps go into a subfolder. Passenger is setup and and my app works great. One problem, If i try to go to these pages using ssl, I get a 404 error. Apparently apache is looking for the literal folder instead of handing it off to Passenger as it normally does. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache for the SSL (port 443) site is probably not set up for Passenger in the same way as for the "normal" (port 80) site.

Comment: I'm gonna put money on this too. Make it listen on 443 as well as 80.

Comment: Ive tried that, but it seems that apache isn't using mod_rails when https is used. Even when I specify a virtualhost for 443. Iam completely baffled, and I need this to work.